# How to send calldata of view/pure functions in remix?

Tags: solidity, remix, calldata

I’m aware that, in Remix, I could input `msg.data` as calldata values and send that as a transaction. It works for me when I send encoded function calls with parameters.

However, how do I encode and send calldata of functions without any parameters or view/pure functions and see the returned values in the console?

For example, in my case, I have a Proxy contract which points to an implementation contract. I'm using the UUPS proxy setup provided by OpenZeppelin. The implementation contract has a view or pure function that looks like this:

```
function owner() public view returns (address) { ... }
```

How should I encode this and pass it into the calldata input in Remix and see the returned value in its console?

[image]

PS: The contract I'm interacting with is a proxy and so it has the `fallback` function. The `owner()` function in the example is in the implementation contract which the proxy is pointed to.

Comment: Please, can you add an example?

Comment: @Kerry99 I have added an example and a screenshot of the calldata input in Remix that I'm referring to. Let me know if this helps to clarify the question. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, can you include all your smart contracts code?

Comment: @Kerry99 I don't really have much of my own code yet. Everything I'm using is what OpenZepplin provided in its UUPS setup. The key thing is I don't know how to encode view/pure functions that return values into the calldata input in Remix and see the returned value in the Remix console.

Comment: I compile the target contract (or the interface), then use the "At address" option to instantiate the target contract at the proxy address.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same question when learning proxies. There are a few ways to do it. You could use [ethers.js encodeFunctionData()](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/interface/#Interface--encoding) ([more info with examples](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/478)) or https://abi.hashex.org/ like this
[image]

Pass the result 8da5cb5b into Remix's calldata window. If execution was successful it worked!

To see the call result

1. Click "Debug" on the transaction
   [image: List item]
2. In debugger window fast forward transaction to the end
   [image: List item]
3. Copy the returned hex value and parse it using something like https://www.convertstring.com/EncodeDecode/HexDecode
   [image]